# calling GetCategories ebay API to list all

Tags: ebay-api

I need to know why this code calling ebay API GetCategoryInfo wont work, ive down similar before to retrieve information but for the life of me I cant seem to get it to work, the error is the foreach, saying Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() could it be this line?

"    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($resp);" the appid is hidden for obvious reasons,

```
$url = 'http://open.api.ebay.com/Shopping?callname=GetCategoryInfo';
$url .= '&appid=' . $appid . '&siteid=3&CategoryID=-1&version=729&IncludeSelector=ChildCategories';

$resp = file_get_contents($url);

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($resp);

foreach($xml->searchResult->Item as $item) 
{
   $categoryName = (string) $item->primaryCategory->categoryName;
   $catid = (string) $item->primaryCategory->CategoryID;
   echo $categoryName . " " . $catid . " <br>\n";  
}
```

changes to reflect working snippet

```
foreach($xml->CategoryArray->Category as $category) 
{
   $categoryName = (string) $category->CategoryName;
   $catid = (string) $category->CategoryID;
   echo $categoryName . " " . $catid . " <br>\n";  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [output](https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/GetCategoryInfo.html#Output) for GetCategoryInfo you can see that `searchResult` is not part of the result.

You need to change your code to:

> foreach($xml->CategoryArray->Category as $category)

Comment: Great, thanks for that, now then, I want to import every category and child categories, what would you think is the best solution or is this a separate thread?